# Angular 4: outputing data with *ngFor not working

Tags: json, angular, http

I'm working on this app with HttpClient, which gets data from a local json file containing images and description (the images are also local) I can log the data (in local array), but I'm having trouble outputing it in the view. This is the request:

```
  export class AppComponent {
  spaceScreens:Array<any>;

    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 

      this.http.get('assets/data/data.json')

        .subscribe(data => {

        this.spaceScreens = data['results'];
          console.log(data);

        }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
          } else {
            console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
          }
        });
    } 

}
```

The JSON:

```
{
    "screenshots": [
        {
          "img": "assets/images/space1.jpg",
          "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
          "liked": "0"
        }, //etc
```

The HTML:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let spaceScreen of spaceScreens; let i = index" >
            <img mat-card-image src="{{ spaceScreen.img }}">
            <mat-card-content>
              <p>{{ spaceScreen.description }}</p>
            </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-actions>
              <button mat-button>
                <i class="material-icons md-18" >favorite</i> LIKE
              </button>
              <button mat-button>
                <i class="material-icons md-18">delete</i> DELETE
              </button>
            </mat-card-actions>
          </mat-card>
```

This is the log:

[image]

I guess the issue has to do with the map? But if I try to map the response I get the word underlined. Can someone give me a help? Thank you

Comment: In your example you are storing `this.spaceScreens = data['results'];`. Should this not be `this.spaceScreens = data['screenshots'];` to match the json you posted

Comment: That's the problem with copy pasting the docs...thanks, that was it. But i'm also validating Niles Tanner answer because it's useful

Comment: Which is not true

Comment: Or if you want to post the answer...@LLai

Comment: well, maybe you're right @Vega, but if LLai won't post it, I'll have to do it myself giving him the credit

Comment: @Mellville sure

Comment: Ah, I was telling about Niles answer in fact, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.spaceScreens = data['results'];
```

should become

```
this.spaceScreens = data['screenshots'];
```

to match your json format.

Comment: Much apreciated @LLai :)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<img mat-card-image src="{{ spaceScreen.img }}">
```

to

```
<img mat-card-image [src]="spaceScreen.img">
```

In angular 2+ you should prefer binding to attributes rather then setting them with string interpolation.

Comment: Why? Those have different purposes.

Comment: I've done similar, and tried to solve this issue, but it didn't worked, the right answer comes from @LLai

Answer (score 1):

Try to use safe-operator ?

```
<img mat-card-image [src]="spaceScreen?.img">
```

Comment: Nope, this is just another approach to use safe-operator.

Comment: Ok, it works, but you know, without matching the json, this would never work